# How to pass tJava output as header data to tRest client component

Tags: java, session-cookies, talend

I am creating a Job to set cookie value for tRestClient component.

To acheive this task i wrote a Java code in tJava component and i am able to extract cookie data with this Java code. Now i want to pass this data to tRestClient component.

Please suggest a way to resolve pass the cookie data.

- **More details:** Below is the expected talend job structure

tJava -> tRestClient

Answer (score 0):

When you link tJava to tRestClient on the Row/Main, it will ask you to copy the target schema. Say yes.

Then in your tJava module, you can set the Row value going into the tRestClient.

```
row1.body = myXMLData;
row1.string = myString;
```

Note that body is a Document type, string is a String.

If you need to do multiple rows, you'll need to change it to a tJavaFlex component and loop it while setting the row in the main section.